# Magento upgrade 2.19 to 2.2

Tags: magento2.2, upgrade, composer, magento-2.1.9

Got this error, no clue how to upgrade:

```
- magento/product-community-edition 2.2.0 requires composer/composer 1.4.1 -> satisfiable by composer/composer[1.4.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.2.0",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.2.0",
        "composer/composer": "1.1.2 as 1.0.0-beta1",
        "iwd/ordermanager": "2.6.0",
        "hellobrave/cookiecompliance": "1.0.4",
        "clarion/customer-attribute": "1.0.0",
        "extait/admin-notify": "1.0.3",
        "amasty/base": "1.0.6",
        "amasty/groupcat": "1.3.1",
        "aheadworks/module-rbslider": "1.1.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.2.2",
        "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "use-include-path": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": "app/code/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": "app/code/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        },
        "magento": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/packages.json"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Comment: composer show -i says 
composer/composer                             1.1.2          Composer helps you declare, manage and install dependencies of PHP projects, ensuring you have the right stack everywhere.

Comment: I have no idea how to upgrade this composer/composer component package

Comment: Getting the same problem, have you found anything more yet?

Comment: Tried this? https://magecomp.com/blog/upgrade-magento-2-x-to-latest-version/

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Access Your Server via SSH**

You need to connect your server via SSH.

**Step 2: Navigate to the Magento 2 Root Directory**

Once your SSH connection is up, you will need to move to your target application folder. In that application folder, you will find the public_html folder which is the root directory of Magento 2.

**Step 3: Upgrade Commands**

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2 --no-update
```

Then execute this all commands

```
 composer update
 rm -rf var/di var/generation
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 php bin/magento setup:di:compile
 php bin/magento cache:clean
 php bin/magento cache:flush
 php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: To get to our problem we already had to go through steps 1 & 2. The error occurs when running composer update

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found the solution...

Apparently changing your composer to was a workaround for updating an earlier version of Magento. But nobody really bothered to revert the change after updating it.

```
 "composer/composer": "1.1.2 as 1.0.0-beta1"
```

So now we should revert the composer.json to its initial state, which is:

```
"composer/composer": "@alpha"
```

It solved the issue for me, I hope it can help anyone else!